# How to do multiple user logins from csv file and process different records from another csv file file in jMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have one doubt regarding login through one csv file and picking some records through another csv file.

I have 2 login id's in one csv file(A) and 1000 records in another Csv file(B), and I kept those login requests in Once Only Controller and after login, how can I process those 1000 requests sequentially row by row without failing any row.

Note: After login only I can do that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to read all the values from one CSV file and proceed, use the following test setup:

- [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) with condition `${__javaScript("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}`

  - [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) set up like:

    [image: CSV Data Set Config]

    - [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with condition `"${myVar}" != "<EOF>"`

      - Login Sampler

Above setup will allow to iterate all entries from the first CSV file and continue with 2nd afterwards. See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article, pay attention to **Reading all Values from the CSV and Continue** chapter for more details.

Answer (score -1):

When configuring the CSV dataset in JMeter, set the setting **Stop Thread on EOF** to *true*. This will stop any thread if all the values within the CSV have been consumed. Also set **Sharing mode** to *All threads*.

Please note that this only works when using a single load generator. At [OctoPerf](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/01/31/highlights-of-2016/), we have implemented [automatic CSV file splitting](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/01/31/highlights-of-2016/) accross multiple load generators. CSV are automatically sent to load generators as well.

[image: JMeter CSV Dataset configuration]